# When using namedWindow from OpenCV it is not updating after I use VideoCapture::open(filename), why?

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

So I have been experimenting with OpenCV and I don't understand the update rules in regards to namedWindow. I would expect to be able to place the lines as either:

```
cv::namedWindow( "Example-in", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
cv::namedWindow( "Example-out", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
g_cap.open( string(argv[1]) );
```

or

```
g_cap.open( string(argv[1]) );
cv::namedWindow( "Example-in", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
cv::namedWindow( "Example-out", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
```

The first way works fine and updates my windows. However, the second way only produces a still image with and without the filter.

Full code here:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;

void example2_5( const cv::Mat & image ) {
    // Create some windows to show the input
    // and output images in.
    //
    //cv::namedWindow( "Example2_5-in", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    //cv::namedWindow( "Example2_5-out", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    // Create a window to show our input image
    //
    cv::imshow( "Example2_5-in", image );
    // Create an image to hold the smoothed output
    //
    cv::Mat out;
    // Do the smoothing
    // ( Note: Could use GaussianBlur(), blur(), medianBlur() or bilateralFilter(). )
    //
    cv::GaussianBlur( image, out, cv::Size(5,5), 3, 3);
    cv::GaussianBlur( out, out, cv::Size(5,5), 3, 3);
    // Show the smoothed image in the output window
    //
    cv::imshow( "Example2_5-out", out );
    // Wait for the user to hit a key, windows will self destruct
    //
    cv::waitKey( 10 );
}

int g_run = 1, g_dontset = 0; //start out in single step mode
cv::Size size(640,360);
cv::VideoCapture g_cap;

void onTrackbarSlide( int pos, void *) {
    g_cap.set( cv::CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, pos );
    if( !g_dontset )
        g_run = 1;
    g_dontset = 0;
}

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    cout<<"g_run :"<<g_run<<"\n g_dontset"<<g_dontset<<endl;
    cv::namedWindow( "Example2_5-in", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cv::namedWindow( "Example2_5-out", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    g_cap.open( string(argv[1]) );
    g_cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
    g_cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 360);
    cv::Mat frame;
    for(;;) {
        cout<<"g_run :"<<g_run<<"\n g_dontset"<<g_dontset<<endl;
        if( g_run != 0 ) {
            g_cap >> frame; if(frame.empty()) break;
            cv::resize(frame,frame,size,0,0,CV_INTER_CUBIC);
            example2_5(frame);
            g_dontset = 1;
            g_run-=1;
        }
        char c = (char) cv::waitKey(10);
        if( c == 's' ) // single step
        {g_run = 1; cout << "Single step, run = " << g_run << endl;}
        if( c == 'r' ) // run mode
        {g_run = -1; cout << "Run mode, run = " << g_run <<endl;}
        if( c == 27 )
            break;
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Apologies for ugliness

Comment: You need to use imshow followed by waitKey to refresh a window

Comment: If you look in the callback example2_5(), it does that for both variations :/